# Allowdiskuse in mongodb crashes mongodb

Tags: mongodb

We have around 20 Million documents in a collection and overall 100 million documents overall in our mongodb for analytics purposes. We use all aggregation and find and filters in mongodb. We tend to use {'allowDiskUse' : true} for most of our reporting purposes as it uses sort by descending order of date. We incurred the following error inspite of setting ulimit as required  in ubuntu:

```
  WiredTiger error (24) [tttt:xxxx][oooo:yyyy], file:WiredTiger.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: /usr/mongodb/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Too many open files
```

Please help

Regards

Kris

Comment: Which version of MongoDB are you on?

Comment: apologies for my delay, we are using mongodb 3.4.10 and ubuntu 16.04 versions respectively

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix too many open files error when aggregating billions of records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30023574/how-to-fix-too-many-open-files-error-when-aggregating-billions-of-records)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20931909/too-many-open-files-while-ensure-index-mongo